# How to use lftp to transfer segmented files?

Tags: linux, lftp

I want to transfer a file from my server to another.The network between these servers isn't very well,so I want to use lftp to speed up.My script is like this:

```
lftp -u user,password -e "set sftp:connect-program 'ssh -a -x -i /key'; mirror --use-pget=5 -i data.tar.gz -r -R  /data/ /tmp; quit" sftp://**.**.**.**:22
```

I found data.tar.gz wasn't segmented, But When I use it to download a file, that will works.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Segmented uploads are not implemented in lftp. If you have ssh access to the server, login there and use lftp to download the file. If there were many files, you could  also upload different files in parallel using -P mirror option.